# Stacked ensemble with H2O.ai from caret models

Tags: r, r-caret, h2o

Is it possible to perform a stacked ensemble with H2O (under R) using previously ran caret models? How could we load caret models to the H2O server?

(I am aware of the existence of the 'caretEnsemble' package, but it does not handle multiclass data).

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only do a stacked ensemble of H2O models, i.e. the models must have been trained on H2O cluster.

Comment: I see. Maybe an alternative could be found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/297546